# Friendly light bulbs, I want them to turn on slowly

Tags: bulb, light

I want that the light bulbs in my house turn on slowly, just like when you use an impedance control, but with a simple switch, is that possible?

Comment: Some LED "bulbs" have a soft-start feature.

Comment: Some switches also have this feature but more information on the type of lighting would be helpful.

Comment: Insteon switches have a user programmable ramp rate.